# How do I sort a DataGrid column based on a field in an embedded Repeater?

Tags: sorting, datagrid, repeater, itemdatabound

I have a DataGrid which has one column that derives its contents from a Repeater that is populated during the DataGrid's ItemDataBound event. I need to be able to sort the DataGrid rows based on the value in the Repeater. Here is a shortened sample of the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid id="dgResults" Runat="server" AllowSorting="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:boundcolumn HeaderText="ID" datafield="group_id" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Group" DataField="group_name" SortExpression="group_name" />
        <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="meeting_start_time">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Sort" Text="Time" CausesValidation="False" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Schedule_Repeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("meeting_start_time", "{0:t}")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, the third column contains the `meeting_start_time`, whose value is displayed via a Repeater.

How do I tell the DataGrid to sort the "Time" column by the `meeting_start_time` values in the Repeater?